# Convert elements into attributes within one short expression when creating XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I found a common method to create XML from tables where elements' names changed into attributes' names. It looks like

```
SELECT  ElementName_1 as "@AttName_1", ElementName_2 as "@AttName_2", ElementName_3 as "@AttName_3", etc..
from table
for XML PATH
```

Is there a method to shorten this kind of converting entry? For example i have dozens of fields\columns and need co convert all of them except one. So, formally it would looks like

```
 (SELECT table.* --> all @attributes --> except 'OneFieldName'
```

If it possible, how it would be noted correctly?

Comment: You should be defining your columns you want anyway, using `SELECT *` in code is a bad habit. But no, there is no "Select all but one column" syntax.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to specify the columns. What if someone add new columns and you are using `SELECT *`?

If you do not want to write the definition itself, you can build it using the [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) system view. It will be something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(QUOTENAME([name]), ' AS "AttName_', [column_id], '"') 
FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [column_id]) AS [column_id]
          ,[name]
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table')
        AND [name] NOT IN ('OneFieldName')
) DS
```

and you can even use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to build the whole `SELECT`:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(CONCAT(QUOTENAME([name]), ' AS "AttName_', [column_id], '"') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [column_id])
FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [column_id]) AS [column_id]
          ,[name]
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table')
        AND [name] NOT IN ('OneFieldName')
) DS
```